# My iPhone 11 running iOS 13.3 won’t give permission to apps to use my camera or microphone

Tags: ios, permission, camera

I’ve rebooted, deleted and reinstalled apps. I’ve also reset my location and security settings.  No deal. This is affecting WhatsApp, Facebook, Instagram, messenger and many more. Sometimes it will say on the permissions page that it is allowing it and it still won’t and sometimes it won’t even give me the option to give permission. But it’s allowing me to insert photos on here. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Photos and Camera are two different settings, access to the Camera doesn‘t automatically grant access to the Photo library as well. There should be a separate option to enable for Photos, e.g. for WhatsApp it looks like this:

[image]

You can try to tap on "Enable Library Access" (from the second screenshot). If this doesn't work I would proceed with reinstalling the apps in question and trying again.